# How to make multiple http calls from the nodejs server with a common callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I want to make multiple http calls in nodejs sever with common callback.
Is there any modules available for doing it?

Comment: What stops you from doing it?

Comment: I am looking for different solutions. Have you encounter such requirement ?

Comment: Take a look onto `async` package https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Do you mean you want to make different http calls and then do something after all of them have finished? Try async module

Comment: Your question is not very clear what exactly you're trying to do and including some of your relevant code would likely clear it up completely and pretty much always leads to a better answer.  Are you trying to just use the same function to process the result from multiple http requests?  Or are you trying to run multiple http requests and then run a function when all of them are done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this Async NPM to solve this.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

```
async.parallel([
        function(callback){
             callback(null,1)
        },
        function(callback){
             callback(null,2)
        },      
    ],
    function(err, results){

       console.log(results); //Output [1,2]

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use async library or underscore.

I often use underscore for this. Assuming you are making n http calls

```
var http_done = _.after(n, function() {
   // final callback
});

for... {
  ajax_call(..., function(response) {
     // Do something with response
     http_done();
  });
}
```